# Find the equation of the normal line to the function.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

Here is the problem as well as my work:

> [image]

**Am I correct?** I am unsure if I correctly related the slope of the tangent line to that of the normal line..

Comment: try to google (3x+sin(3*x),1/6*x). You'll get a graph and be able to visually inspect your solution.

Comment: @camel Great idea, found my mistake! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slope of a line normal to a curve is the negative reciprocal of the slope of the tangent line at a given point on the curve.

So if $m$ is the slope of the line tangent to the curve at $(a, b)$, then $-\frac 1m$ is the slope of the line normal to the tangent line at $(a, b)$.

So you want your line to have the slope of $-\frac 16$.

Otherwise, you've done well.

Comment: Right, I forgot about the negative, I simply took the reciprocal. So the equation would be y = -1/6x then?

Comment: Yes indeed, McB.